# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/XboxVoting/ownedGames] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've looked through other answers on here as best I can, but nothing seems to exactly fit my issue/solve my problem. Essentially, I get the above error when I try and access ownedGames from my index.

I feel like I have the mapping done correctly, but obviously I don't. So here I'll post any files that seem like they may be relevant.

**index.html** (where I click links that give the errors)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>xbox voting</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="wantedGames">Vote on Games!</a> <br />
    <a href="ownedGames">View the Games We Own!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="net.nerdery.xboxvoting.controller" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**GameController**

```
package net.nerdery.xboxvoting.controller;

import java.util.Map;


import net.nerdery.xboxvoting.domain.Game;
import net.nerdery.xboxvoting.service.GameService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class GameController {

    @Autowired
    private GameService gameService;

    @RequestMapping("/XboxVoting/ownedGames")
    public String listOwnedGames(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("game", new Game());
        map.put("ownedGamesList", gameService.listOwnedGames());

        return "game";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/wantedGames")
    public String listWantedGames(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("game", new Game());
        map.put("wantedGamesList", gameService.listOwnedGames());

        return "game";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addGame(@ModelAttribute("game")
    Game game, BindingResult result) {

        gameService.addGame(game);

        return "redirect:/ownedGames";
    }

}
```

I'm sure it's some silly syntax error I'm missing somewhere, but I'm new to Spring (just started today) and have hardly any idea what I'm doing. So thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you tell when you are getting this error mean when you click on any URL or when you submit any form? Also add that details.

Comment: Essentially any URL. I have an index file with two links off of it, ownedGames and wantedGames, and both return a No mapping found error for that file (i.e. wantedGames will give WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/XboxVoting/wantedGames] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: Can you add HTML code snippet used for links? `href` to be more specific.

Comment: Added in the contents of index, including the href tags.

Answer (score 1):

you need change   
    `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`
to
`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute path in href so you should specify complete path there
or instead of that use relative path (append / in beginning of href)  like

```
 <a href="/wantedGames">Vote on Games!</a> <br />
 <a href="/XboxVoting/ownedGames">View the Games We Own!</a>
```

Also try adding `method = RequestMethod.GET` to your controller.

I am not sure about your URL structure.

Comment: This returns a 404. "The requested resource (/ownedGames) is not available." to be specific.

Comment: @user1516707: It looks like problem is with the url used in `href`. Try few combinations. I have also updated my answer

Comment: Messed around with just about every combination I can think of, and added requestmethod.get to the controller. Everything gives either a 404, or the mapping error.